# Importing an encrypted Cython module in Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, encryption, cython

How could I import an encrypted .pyd Cythonized module into Python without exposing my decrypted .pyd bytecode module to disk?
What my thought process is so far:

1. with open( my encrypted file) and read() to store the encrypted file to a variable.
2. decrypt using a cryptoraphy library and my secret key.
3. import the decrypted .pyd module from memory.

The last step is what I cant figure out.
I have seen numerous solutions for accomplishing this with .py and pyc modules but I am especially interested in cythonized .pyd modules. Would something like this be possible?
I am using python-3.7 and Windows with cython version 0.29.13

Comment: I don't think there's an existing solution to do this. Let's suppose you managed to do it though.... where is your secret key stored? Presumably in the unencrypted code? And what's to stop a user from finding it out?

Comment: Well, that's a bummer... there are a couple of ways for hiding the secret key, haven't settled on one yet but it's definitely not going to be inside the code.